# Show that, given a compact set $A\subset \vec{E}$, with $\vec{E}$ a Banach n.v.s, $\overline{co}A$ is compact

Tags: general-topology

I was trying to prove the following . Consider $\ell_2$ with the norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ and consider the set
$$
A=\left \{0,e_1,\frac{1}{2}e_2.\ldots,\frac{1}{n}e_n,\ldots \right \} 
$$
with $e_j=(0,0,\ldots,1,0,\ldots)$ the sequent in $\ell_2$ with a $1$ in the $j$ coordinate.

the problem is:

> Show that $\overline{co}A$ is compact

what I've done: Let $(x_n)\subset \overline{co}A$. I want to show that there is a subsequent $(x_{n_j})_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ covergent to some point in $\overline{co}A$. We know that, as for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is a sequent $(x_k^n)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\subset coA$ such that
$$
x_k^n\to x_n\quad \text{when }k\to \infty
$$
It's known that I can take $(x_{k(n)}^n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that:
$$
\|x_n-x_{k(n)}^n\|\leq \frac{1}{n}
$$
Then, I just need to prove that every sequent in $coA$ has a convergent subsequet. And here I don't know how to go on

Comment: It's easier to show that $coA$ is totally bounded.

Comment: @Etienne why that's sufficient?

Comment: If you prove this, then $\overline{co}A$ will be totally bounded as well; and "closed+totally bounded" implies "compact" (in a complete metric space).

Comment: @Etienne Now I get it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $A$ is totally bounded.
2. Fix $\varepsilon\gt 0$. There is an integer $N$ and $x^1,\dots,x^N\in A$ such that $\bigcup_{j=1}^NB(x^j,\varepsilon)\supset A$. Since $[0,1]^N$ is totally bounded, there are an integer $M$ and $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_M\in[0,1]^N$ such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^MB_{\mathbb R^N}(\lambda_j,\varepsilon)\supset [0,1]^M$ and the sum of the coordinated of each $\lambda_j$ is $1$. The balls of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at 
   $$\sum_{i=1}^N\lambda_j^{(i)}x^i,1\leqslant j\leqslant M$$
   cover the convex hull of $A$.
3. The closure of a totally bounded subset of a Banach space is compact.

---

Remark: we actually proved that the closed convex hull of a totally bounded subset of Banach space is compact. One could use the special features of $A$ in order to give a simpler proof.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Those special features of $A$ you say have to do with the fact that the elements of are convergent to $0$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: but you say to use that fact in order to prove that coA is totally bounded,right?